# nvidia drivers dual screen xorg.conf

Tags: 10.10, xorg, nvidia, 64-bit, multiple-monitors

I had dual screen working previously. Now every time I try to setup dual screens and reboot. I get logged in as tty mode, i am able to get one screen working, or have my desktop span both screen ( one huge screen) what i require is two independent screens, that I can drag windows between.

This is frustrating, i am sure you can imagine. This issue now is whether or not xorg.conf is used anymore. from my understanding isn't.

I would appreciate any help that you guys provide in solving this issue.

Thanks.

Edit: Here is my xorg.conf generated by the nvidia-settings command, when i select separate screens.

http://pastie.org/1350919

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled the drivers and selected twin view and it managed to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get it working with one screen on the `nvidia` driver?
2. Run `gksu nvidia-settings` and under the screen configuration part, get both screens working.
3. Click the Save X Configuration File button on that same page. This is why you need to run nvidia-settings as root.

Then when you reboot, it should remember your settings.

Comment: i do that every time i think the xorg.conf is messed up. I pasted it above mind taking a quick look.

Comment: btw, I cant get both screen working from the settings. it says i require a restart of x, and if just restart that it doesn't do anything. What should i do next?

Comment: That X config is very odd. Why isn't twinview enabled for starters?

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10, and no dual view anymore..
I tried everything above, but no help..
Finally, I was brave, and in the menu System Tools -> System Settings, I clicked on "Additional Drivers" (under Hardware), and installed 'version current-updates' instead of 'version 173-updates'.
After a reboot, I had version 280.13.
And finally, in menu Other -> NVIDIA X Server Settings, the "X Server Display Configuration" was correct. And I could select and configure the 2nd display.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links could be of some help:

http://hobbylobby.wordpress.com/2007/09/08/dual-monitors-in-ubuntu-xorgconf-driver-ati-card/

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=221174&page=63

If not, could you paste your xorg.conf here?

Comment: done and done no mas. pasted the xorg.conf above.

Answer (score 0):

When this sort of thing happens I generally

mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup

and then do nvidia-settings if I'm using the nvidia settings or dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg otherwise.

If there is no existing xorg.conf these programs will automagically generate a new one. Sometimes this solves problems, sometimes it creates them; but having the old and new versions of xorg.conf to diff can be instructive for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Which nvidia package on your system is installed?

On my Natty I have `nvidia-173` installed  - because I own an *old* GeForce FX 5200.
After selecting "Separate X Server" by enabling TV-Out in `nvidia-settings` and restarting my X-Server never came up.

After looking around I found out that `nvidia-settings` wrote a defect *BusID* into my `xorg.conf`.
I fixed it by doing:

1. `sudo lspci | grep VGA`

   - I got out: *01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5200] (rev a1)*
2. replacing `BusID "?@?:?:?"` with `BUSID "PCI:1:0:0"`
3. `service gdm restart` :)