# X server display configuration page will not load

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, twinview

The X Server Display Configuration Page will not load due to "failed to query NoScanout for screen 0".

So, the  Display Control Panel in System Settings does not recognize that the second monitor exists and it thinks that the primary monitor unknown.  How do I get ubuntu to recognize both my monitors and set them up in twinview?  Please give detailed instructions as I am very new to this.  I am running Ubuntu 11.10

I have a Dell u2410 and a Vizio va19l hdtv10t lcd displays. running from an Nvidia Geforce4 MX400 video card. The Dell is using the video card's vga interface and the Vizio is using its hdmi input from the the video card's dvi interface. The resolution of both is set to 1600x1080.  Everything works perfectly in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and updating the NVIDIA driver to current (280 instead of 173) solved my problem. 
See also [my answer in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16310/nvidia-drivers-dual-screen-xorg-conf/94840#94840).